# zoom content of iframe in webapp

Tags: html, css, iframe, zooming

the content I want to display is not optimized for mobile device.
So I need to zoom the content out.

It is a webapp, I can not use javascript.

This is, what I basically use:

`<div style="-webkit-overflow-scrolling:
 touch;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y: auto;height:400px; margin:
 -1.2em;">  <iframe src="http://..." style="width:100%;height:390px;border: none;"></iframe></div>`

For zoom i found:

```
-webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
```

so i tried:

```
<div style="-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y: auto;height:400px; margin: -1.2em;-webkit-transform: scale(0.8);">
    <iframe src="http://..." style="width:100%;height:390px;border: none;"></iframe></div>
```

but the result was, that the iframe was zoomed too.
See: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9sBI.jpg

Can you help me? 
Thank you and BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok i solved it

i used

```
<div style="
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
     overflow-x:hidden;
     overflow-y: auto;
     height:800px;
     width:850px;
     margin: -1.2em;">
     <iframe src="http://" style="
         width:800px;
         height:800px;
         -webkit-transform: scale(0.4);
         -webkit- transform-origin: 0 0;
         border: none;">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

if the iframe gets smaller, i simply increate the size of it.
50% of 200% = 100%